# Vertical aligning of div elements within list items

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a layout like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ATgNs/).
How can I align each `div.product_image` to the vertical middle of `<li>` items if I don't have fixed height of list item or image and in the same time be sure that images won't overlap each other?

Answer (score 1):

A table may work, but you won't like it. Then JS may help. The "normal" way to do it would need to use `min-height & min-width` in `<li>`, then using 2 divs. 1st `position: absolute;` 1px*1px `top:50%;left:50%;`, 2nd a relative div `left:-Xpx; top:-Ypx; width:2*X; height:2*Y;` (<- that would be static), then just place whatever you want inside.